# .htaccess redirect within root directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have copy and pasted the new index.html file I made into the old one. However, I need to now redirect users from the old .html files to the new index page which has anchor links. I have seen 301 redirects online but none of the examples included items that were in the same folder on the same domain. I tried to use the following, in a .htaccess file, but it didn't work.

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 /about_us.html #AboutUs
Redirect 301 /contact_us.html #GetQuote
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your both 301 redirects are missing the "target path" perameter

Comment: @starkeen - OP wants to redirect to index with only the anchor link showing. See my answer which explains this.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to prepend the target paths with a leading slash:

```bash
Redirect 301 /about_us.html /#AboutUs
```

This will redirect `/about_us.html` to `/#AboutUs`.

If you omit the leading slash, then Apache will mistake the target path for a comment, and throw an Internal Server Error.

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log. Is the error.

Comment: Do you know what version of Apache you are running? And are you able to check your server error logs?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to redirect people to a different page because a URL has changed. Redirect to a Different URL using the Meta Tag "Refresh".

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com/new-index.html">
```

You can change the amount of time that this redirecting page is displayed by changing the number in the refresh **content="5** portion of the meta tag statement.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.example.com/new-index.html">
```

> Note that meta tags go in the **`<HEAD> </HEAD>`** section of the HTML
>   document.

You can also use this line of code Apache **.htaccess** redirect.

```
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /web/old-index.html http://www.example.com/web/new-index.html
```

Hope this will help to resolve your issue !!

Comment: For the .htaccess method, do I need to include the folder name in the web root directory? /thisweb/index.html It starts with an ! is that an illegal character?